# SQL Server stored procedure to link a column based on another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClIy6.png)

| TaskID | TaskNumber | RequestorName | SenderName | LinkedTaskNumber | TaskStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WR00001 | Requester1 | Sender1 |  | 0 |
| 2 | WR00002 | Requester2 | Sender2 |  | 0 |
| 3 | WR00003 | Requester3 | Sender3 |  | 0 |
| 4 | WR00004 | Requester4 | Sender4 | WR00003 | 0 |
| 5 | WR00005 | Requester5 | Sender5 | WR00003 | 0 |
| 6 | WR00006 | Requester6 | Sender6 |  | 0 |
| 7 | WR00007 | Requester7 | Sender7 | WR00006 | 0 |
| 8 | WR00008 | Requester8 | Sender8 | WR00006 | 0 |
| 9 | WR00009 | Requester9 | Sender9 |  | 0 |
| 10 | WR00010 | Requester10 | Sender10 |  | 0 |

Can someone help me getting the below output with a SQL Server stored procedure?

LinkedTaskNumber (column 5) should show the TaskNumber (column 1) which are linked to each other.

e.g.: From above table,
WR00003 has **Null** value in LinkedTaskNumber. However, its linked with WR00004 and WR00005 as per LinkedTaskNumber column. So the output of WR00003 for LinkedTaskNumber is WR00004 and WR00005.

Similarly, WR00004 has **WR00003** value in LinkedTaskNumber. So its linked with WR00003. Since WR00003 is also linked with WR00005, the output of WR00004 for LinkedTaskNumber is WR00003 and WR00005

Required output:

[Required Output Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLGIO.png)

| TaskID | TaskNumber | RequestorName | SenderName | LinkedTaskNumber | TaskStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WR00001 | Requester1 | Sender1 |  | 0 |
| 2 | WR00002 | Requester2 | Sender2 |  | 0 |
| 3 | WR00003 | Requester3 | Sender3 | WR00004; WR00005 | 0 |
| 4 | WR00004 | Requester4 | Sender4 | WR00003; WR00005 | 0 |
| 5 | WR00005 | Requester5 | Sender5 | WR00003; WR00004 | 0 |
| 6 | WR00006 | Requester6 | Sender6 | WR00007; WR00008 | 0 |
| 7 | WR00007 | Requester7 | Sender7 | WR00006; WR00008 | 0 |
| 8 | WR00008 | Requester8 | Sender8 | WR00006; WR00007 | 0 |
| 9 | WR00009 | Requester9 | Sender9 |  | 0 |
| 10 | WR00010 | Requester10 | Sender10 |  | 0 |

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far and try to explain how you understand what this procedure should do to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: What DBMS do you use? MS Sql, PostgreSQL, etc. ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2017

Comment: How is `WR00004` linked to `WR00005` ? I don't see any such direct relation in the source table, but see it is linked in the Required output table. Are you considering transitive links as well ?

Comment: Since WR00003 is linked with WR00004 and WR00005

Comment: You shouldn't put more than one value into one column. If it were a separate row, you could achieve what you want with simple join or subquery and where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

### Recursively Crawling through Hierarchy to Find All Related Tasks

My script below recursively crawls through the hierarchy to find any relationships and list each one in a row. Most recursion examples use JOIN  traverse up through ancestors or down through descendants, but this uses CROSS APPLY to "crawl" up/down/left/right to find all relationships, which is what I think you are going for.

Then to prevent circular references, RelatedPath is used to track history of matches

### Data Setup

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Task
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DistinctRelationships

CREATE TABLE #Task (TaskID INT Primary Key,TaskNum Char(7),LinkedTaskNum Char(7))
INSERT INTO #Task
VALUES
(1,'WR00001',NULL)
,(2,'WR00002',NULL)
,(3,'WR00003',NULL)
,(4,'WR00004','WR00003')
,(5,'WR00005','WR00003')
,(6,'WR00006',NULL)
,(7,'WR00007','WR00006')
,(8,'WR00008','WR00006')
,(9,'WR00009',NULL)
,(10,'WR00010',NULL)

/*Recommended optimizations*/
Create Unique Index uq_TaskNum On #Task(TaskNum) Include (LinkedTaskNum);
Create NonClustered Index ix On #Task (LinkedTaskNum, TaskNum)
Alter Table #Task
Add Constraint FK Foreign Key(LinkedTaskNum) References #Task(TaskNum) 
GO
```

### Solution

```
;With cteNum
As
(
    Select  a.TaskNum
            ,RootTaskNum = a.TaskNum
            ,a.LinkedTaskNum
            ,RecursionLevel = 0
            ,RelatedPath = Cast(Concat('|', a.TaskNum, '|') As Varchar(Max))
    From    #Task As a
    Union All
    Select      b.TaskNum
                ,a.RootTaskNum
                ,b.LinkedTaskNum
                ,a.RecursionLevel + 1
                ,RelatedPath = Cast(Concat(a.RelatedPath, b.TaskNum, '|') As Varchar(Max))
    From        cteNum As a /*Current*/
    Cross Apply (
                Select dta.TaskNum,dta.LinkedTaskNum
                From #Task As dta With(Index(uq_TaskNum))
                Where a.TaskNum = dta.LinkedTaskNum /*Where current is related of another record*/
                Union All
                Select dtb.TaskNum,dtb.LinkedTaskNum
                From #Task As dtb With(Index(ix))
                Where a.LinkedTaskNum = dtb.TaskNum /*Where related is TaskNum of another row*/
                ) As b
    Where a.relatedPath not like Concat('%|',b.TaskNum,'|%') /*If previously used, don't join again. Prevents circular references hitting infinite loop*/
        And a.TaskNum <> b.TaskNum /*Don't join to same record*/
)

Select RootTaskNum,TaskNum
INTO #DistinctRelationships /*1 row per task num and its related task (no matter how distant the relationship*/
From cteNum As a
Where RootTaskNum <> TaskNum /*Filter out "relationship" to itself*/
Order by 1,2
Option (MaxRecursion 0);

/*Formatting Results*/
WITH cte_RelationshipCSV AS (
    SELECT RootTaskNum
        ,RelatedTasks = STRING_AGG(TaskNum,',')
    FROM #DistinctRelationships
    GROUP BY RootTaskNum
)
SELECT A.TaskID
    ,A.TaskNum
    ,B.RelatedTasks
FROM #Task AS A
LEFT JOIN cte_RelationshipCSV AS B
    ON A.TaskNum = B.RootTaskNum
```